# How to display a DateTime with chosen date parts, but in the order of the FormatProvider?

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting

I want to display the date in the order that the culture provides, but with the elements I want only.

The DateTime.Tostring() method has [a list of patterns that are very useful](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/demos/datetimeformats.aspx) but I would like a very small change in it.

*The CultureInfo used in the following the following code are chosen as example, I don't want to rely on a specific list of CultureInfo, if possible*

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

string nowString = now.ToString("m", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
Console.WriteLine(nowString);

nowString = now.ToString("m", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
Console.WriteLine(nowString);
```

displays :

> April 12
>   12 avril

I would like a pattern that display the abbreviation of the month and the day, but that keeps the correct order from the specified CultureInfo.
using the pattern **"MMM dd**" will always display the month's abbreviation first, followed by the day, breaking the french order for example.

Any way to achieve that without too much custom code?

Comment: It's not .NET but Microsoft needs to do similar to this to remove seconds from the time in the taskbar. Otherwise it follows the culture short time. (There's a The Old New Thing blog entry on /why/ the seconds are dropped: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/10/55256.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, Microsoft "[accepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier)" the date to be formatted like this:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 8, 29, 19, 27, 15);

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("ddd d MMM", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Displays Fri 29 Aug
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("ddd d MMM", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));
// Displays ven. 29 août
```

So don't think that Framework previewed something for your case.

You will need to find a **workaround** like this:

```
private string GetCultureMonthDay(CultureInfo culture, DateTime date)
{
    return string.Format(culture, "{0:" + 
      culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern.Replace("MMMM", "MMM") + "}", date);
}
```

usage:

```
?Console.WriteLine(GetCultureMonthDay(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), now));
12 avr.

?Console.WriteLine(GetCultureMonthDay(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), now));
Apr 12
```

Comment: That's what I figured out and the reason of my question on SO. :)
If no better solution, I will settle for "MMM d"

Comment: nice! thanks for the trick. I wonder if it would be possible to implement this as a IFromatProvider for the ToString method, and have it completely transparent somehow :). But that's already a great solution to my problem :) thanks

Comment: notice that this method presumes that the MonthDayPattern contain `MMMM`. For Fr and En, and probably for a lot of cultures this works. but there could be other cases.