# HowTo: obtain culture dateTime format

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting, globalization

```
?string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:d}", now)
"4/12/2010"

?string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), "{0:d}", now)
"12/04/2010"
```

I want to write a method: `string GetDateFormat(culture)`

```
?GetDateFormat(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
"M/d/yyyy"

?GetDateFormat(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"))
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the [ShortDatePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx) property:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Answer (score 2):

The more general purpose answer is to use [GetAllDateTimePatterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dah0ktz1.aspx):

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d')[0]
```

Note that GetCultureInfo will not pick up any user overrides.

Comment: this was a way to resolve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621928/how-to-display-a-datetime-with-chosen-date-parts-but-in-the-order-of-the-formatp/2622391#2622391